# A couple of Perl subtleties

Tags: perl

I've been programming in Perl for a while, but I never have understood a couple of subtleties about Perl:

The use and the setting/unsetting of the $_ variable confuses me.  For instance, why does

```
# ...
shift @queue;
($item1, @rest) = split /,/;
```

work, but (at least for me)

```
# ...
shift @queue;
/some_pattern.*/ or die();
```

does not seem to work?

Also, I don't understand the difference between iterating through a file using `foreach` versus `while`.  For instance,I seem to be getting different results for

```
while(<SOME_FILE>){  
    # Do something involving $_        
}
```

and

```
foreach (<SOME_FILE>){
    # Do something involving $_
}
```

Can anyone explain these subtle differences?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
shift @queue;
($item1, @rest) = split /,/;
```

If I understand you correctly, you seem to think that this shifts off an element from `@queue` to `$_`. That is not true.

The value that is shifted off of `@queue` simply disappears The following `split` operates on whatever is contained in `$_` (which is independent of the `shift` invocation).

```
while(<SOME_FILE>){  
    # Do something involving $_        
}
```

Reading from a filehandle in a `while` statement is special: It is equivalent to

```
while ( defined( $_ = readline *SOME_FILE ) ) {
```

This way, you can process even colossal files line-by-line.

On the other hand,

```
for(<SOME_FILE>){  
    # Do something involving $_        
}
```

will first load the entire file as a list of lines into memory. Try a 1GB file and see the difference.

Comment: The answer would be improved with some more emphasis on an additional point. The `while(<FILE>)` form does more than check whether `$_` is defined. It also makes the assignment to `$_` in the first place. Other `while` loops do not assign to `$_`: for example, `while(@foo)`.

Comment: I'd add that in order to know when `$_` is used implicitly you must RTFM.

Comment: I'd add that naming $_ explicitly will help the next person who reads your code immensely.

Answer (score 5):

Another, albeit subtle, difference between:

```
while (<FILE>) {
}
```

and:

```
foreach (<FILE>) {
}
```

is that while() will modify the value of $_ outside of its scope, whereas, foreach() makes $_ local.  For example, the following will die:

```
$_ = "test";
while (<FILE1>) {
    print "$_";
}
die if $_ ne "test";
```

whereas, this will not:

```
$_ = "test";
foreach (<FILE1>) {
    print "$_";
}
die if $_ ne "test";
```

This becomes more important with more complex scripts.  Imagine something like:

```
sub func1() {
    while (<$fh2>) {  # clobbers $_ set from <$fh1> below
        <...>
    }
}

while (<$fh1>) {
    func1();
    <...>
}
```

Personally, I stay away from using $_ for this reason, in addition to it being less readable, etc.

Comment: I wasn't aware of *this* difference between `foreach` and `while` with regard to `$_`!

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the 2nd question:

```
while (<FILE>) {
}
```

and

```
foreach (<FILE>) {
}
```

Have the same functional behavior, including setting `$_`.  The difference is that `while()` evaluates `<FILE>` in a scalar context, while `foreach()` evaluates `<FILE>` in a list context.  Consider the difference between:

```
$x = <FILE>;
```

and

```
@x = <FILE>;
```

In the first case, `$x` gets the first line of `FILE`, and in the second case `@x` gets the *entire* file.  Each entry in `@x` is a different line in `FILE`.

So, if `FILE` is very big, you'll waste memory slurping it all at once using `foreach (<FILE>)` compared to `while (<FILE>)`.  This may or may not be an issue for you.

The place where it really matters is if `FILE` is a pipe descriptor, as in:

```
open FILE, "some_shell_program|";
```

Now `foreach(<FILE>)` must wait for `some_shell_program` to complete before it can enter the loop, while `while(<FILE>)` can read the output of `some_shell_program` one line at a time and execute in parallel to `some_shell_program`.

That said, the behavior with regard to `$_` remains unchanged between the two forms.

Answer (score 2):

foreach evaluates the entire list up front.  while evaluates the condition to see if its true each pass.  while should be considered for incremental operations, foreach only for list sources.

For example:

```
my $t= time() + 10 ;
while ( $t > time() ) { # do something }
```

Answer (score 1):

StackOverflow: [*What’s the difference between iterating over a file with foreach or while in Perl?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585341/whats-the-difference-between-iterating-over-a-file-with-foreach-or-while-in-perl/585371#585371)

Comment: This would be better as a comment

Answer (score 0):

`while` only checks if the value is true, `for` also places the value in `$_`, except in some circumstances. For example `<>` will set `$_` if used in a `while` loop.

to get similar behaviour of:

```
foreach(qw'a b c'){
    # Do something involving $_
}
```

You have to set `$_` explicitly.

```
while( $_ = shift @{[ qw'a b c' ]} ){  
    # Do something involving $_        
}
```

---

It is better to explicitly set your variables

```
for my $line(<SOME_FILE>){
}
```

or better yet

```
while( my $line = <SOME_FILE> ){
}
```

which will only read in the file one line at a time.

---

Also [`shift`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html) doesn't set `$_` unless you specifically ask it too

```
$_ = shift @_;
```

And [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) works on `$_` by default. If used in scalar, or void context will populate `@_`.

Answer (score 0):

It is to avoid this sort of confusion that it's considered better form to avoid using the implicit $_ constructions.

```
my $element = shift @queue;
($item,@rest) = split /,/ , $element;
```

or

```
($item,@rest) = split /,/, shift @queue;
```

likewise

```
while(my $foo = <SOMEFILE>){

do something 

}
```

or

```
foreach my $thing(<FILEHANDLE>){

  do something

}
```

Comment: Considered better form by who?  Just because someone might find it confusing is no reason to make such a blanket generalization against a language construct which might prove helpful in other situations.

Comment: It's better form in almost any context where clarity is valued over brevity, and readabililty considered more useful than minor optimisations.

Comment: It is definitely better form to avoid $_ when writing longer scripts, because changes to its value can make debugging quite difficult. See "Perl Best Practices" for more detail: http://books.google.com/books?id=gJf9tI2mytIC&dq=Perl+Best+Practices&printsec=frontcover&source=bn&hl=en&ei=4ESUSrbbK46SsgPF7ITgDw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4#v=onepage&q=&f=false

Answer (score 0):

Please read `perldoc perlvar` so that you will have an idea of the different variables in Perl.

[perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).