# Perl Reading from one file, writing contents to another file on Windows

Tags: windows, perl, file-io

I am very new to Perl and its syntax. I've done a bit of research about reading from one file and writing to another. I've written a short piece of code that doesnt seem to be giving me any error but it also doesn't write to the file. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $defaultfile = 'C:\\Glenn Scott C\\AUTO IOX\\IOMETER FILES\\test.txt';
my $mainfile = 'C:\\Glenn Scott C\\AUTO IOX\\IOMETER FILES\\IOMETERFILECREATOR.txt';

open FILE, $defaultfile;
open FILE2, $mainfile;
while (my $line = <FILE>)
{
     print FILE2($line);
 }
close FILE;
close FILE2;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close, but not quite.

- open is best done with 3 arguments. `open ( my $default_fh, '<', $defaultfile ) or die $!;`
- [`print`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html) to a file handle doesn't work like that. It's `print {$main_fh} $line;`
- you should test `open` for success. An `or die $!` is sufficient.

So this would be what you need:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $defaultfile = 'C:\\Glenn Scott C\\AUTO IOX\\IOMETER FILES\\test.txt';
my $mainfile =
    'C:\\Glenn Scott C\\AUTO IOX\\IOMETER FILES\\IOMETERFILECREATOR.txt';

open( my $default_fh, "<", $defaultfile ) or die $!;
open( my $main_fh,    ">", $mainfile )    or die $!;
while ( my $line = <$default_fh> ) {
    print {$main_fh} $line;
}
close $default_fh;
close $main_fh;
```

Comment: Ah Thanks alot for the help! syntax really got me there

Comment: What surprises me a bit is that you didn't get any errors. I would have thought the print statement would error. It's trying to call a subroutine called 'FILE2' which doesn't exist. I get `Undefined subroutine &main::FILE2 called `;

Comment: Can I please ask what is the difference between looping over a file handle with `while` or using `foreach` ?

Comment: `foreach` or `for` will access the file handle in list context. It will therefore trigger reading the whole file in advance, put it in an array and iterate that array. A `while` loop reads one line at a time. (Delimited by `$/` which is newline by default). So the `foreach` is at best redundant, and at worst wastes memory. (Unless you actually need to hold the file content in memory).

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585341/whats-the-difference-between-iterating-over-a-file-with-foreach-or-while-in-per