# All values are not run in a loop

Tags: perl

I'm reading a file and then running a for loop for each value. My script is stopping after executing the first value. The file_detail.txt has multiple lines. But it is not proceeding to the next value. My script looks something like this --

```
    open (my $fh, "<", "$mycrdir/file_detail.txt" );
foreach(my $value = <$fh>) {
    chomp($value);
    if ($value eq "abc") {
        qx/"mkdir $mydir"/;
        func1($mycrnum,$mydir,$value,%envparams);
        func2($mycrnum,$mydir,$value,%envparams);
    }
    elsif($value eq "123") 
    {
        qx/"mkdir $mydir"/;
        func1($mycrnum,$mydir,$value,%envparams);
        func2($mycrnum,$mydir,$value,%envparams);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do the functions `func1()` and `func2()` do?

Comment: Also what does your data file look like?

Comment: You may want to take a look at answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585341/whats-the-difference-between-iterating-over-a-file-with-foreach-or-while-in-per

Comment: Please show content of data file (file_detail.txt) which you are reffering in your code.

Answer (score 5):

Your code needs:

1. use warnings; use strict;
2. error handling on `open`
3. error handling on `qx`, i.e. replace it with `system` since you do not care about the output, or better yet, with `File::Path::mkpath()`
4. change the `foreach` to a `while`
5. add an `else` clause to your loop

Try this:

**Input**

```
123
456
abc
def
```

**Program**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Path qw( make_path );

my ($mycrnum, $mydir, %envparams);

$mydir = 'bar';
my $file = "foo.txt";
open (my $fh, "<", "$file")
    or die "Unable to open '$file' : $!";

while(my $value = <$fh>) {
        chomp($value);
        print "Value is '$value'\n";
        if ($value eq "abc") {
            unless (-d $mydir) {
                make_path($mydir)
                    or die "Unable to mkdir '$mydir'";
            }
            func1($mycrnum,$mydir,$value,%envparams);
            func2($mycrnum,$mydir,$value,%envparams);
        }
        elsif($value eq "123")
        {
            unless (-d $mydir) {
                make_path($mydir)
                    or die "Unable to mkdir '$mydir'";
            }
            func1($mycrnum,$mydir,$value,%envparams);
            func2($mycrnum,$mydir,$value,%envparams);
        }
        else {
            print "Don't know what to do with line '$value'\n";
        }
}

sub func1 {
    print "You called func1\n";
}

sub func2 {
    print "You called func2\n";
}
```

**Output**

```
Value is '123'
You called func1
You called func2
Value is '456'
Don't know what to do with line '456'
Value is 'abc'
You called func1
You called func2
Value is 'def'
Don't know what to do with line 'def'
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info. I was error handling for open. For others, I followed your suggestion. I tried while, but then also it was exiting after first execution. I used defined inside while and it is working now. Thanks for all the help and detailed info.

Comment: @parthodas: You don't need to call `defined`. `while ( my $value = <$fh> ) { ... }` does it for you and works fine

Answer (score 3):

Change your `foreach` to `while`.

`my $value = <$fh>` returns a single value, which is the first line of the file.  `foreach` then receives that single value and loops over only that one value, after which the loop terminates without reading the next line from `$fh`.

Answer (score 0):

Either use while loop as Dave mentioned or slurp the file in an array then loop over array using foreach.

```
use IO::All;

my @lines = io($filename)->slurp;

foreach (@lines){
    #work on each line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, here is an other solution, if I mean well the problem ...

```
open FH, "$mycrdir/file_detail.txt" || die $!;
while(<$FH>) {
    chomp;
    if (/^abc$/) {
        ...
    }
    elsif(/^123$/) {
        ...
    }
}
close FH;
```